# Как настроить сеть ETTH?

Tags: сеть, linux

Подключил сеть по технологии *ETTH*. Не знаю, как прописаться.

В *ADSL* сеть обозначалась автоматически.

Система *Linux*.

Кака настроить сеть?

Comment: Для начала хотелось бы узнать подробности: 1. какая система? Linux-ов очень много и настройка их различна 2. как подключили именно? какой сетевой интерфейс?будут ответы - скажу как настроить

Answer (score 1):

> Подключил сеть по технологии ETTH

«технология» [*etth*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETTH) — это (с точки зрения клиента) самый обыкновенный [fast ethernet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet).

значит, и «настраивать» его надо, как «самый обыкновенный» *fast ethernet*. эта процедура обычно дистро-специфична и подробно изложена на сайте дистрибутива.

в современных версиях дистрибутивов частенько стараются унифицировать настройку сети с помощью демона *network-manager*: например, в *desktop-environment*-ы (типа *gnome*, *kde*, *xfce* и т.д. и т.п.) добавляют что-то вроде «апплетов» для настройки сети, являющихся «графическим» интерфейсом к вышеупомянутому демону. можно воспользоваться таким «апплетом» и настроить «самое обыкновенное» *ethernet*-подключение с получением параметров по протоколу *dhcp*.

---

судя по выдаче поисковиков, провайдеры в случае *etth* могут **в дополнение** использовать (как и при любом *ethernet*-подключении) ещё и какую-нибудь инкапсуляцию пакетов (для ограничения доступа к «интернету» и учёта трафика), типа *pppoe*.

настроить такую инкапсуляцию можно, например, с помощью тех же самых «апплетов» — «обёрток» вокруг *network-manager*-а.

только следует уточнить у провайдера, какую именно технологию инкапсуляции они используют.